# Como recuperar os dados no firebase?

Tags: firebase

Olá sou novo no firebase, e estou tendo dificuldades de recuperar alguns valores.

**SQL**

```
select * from aparmanto where andar< 22 or quarto=>2;

select * from aparmanto where andar> 22 and quarto=>2;
```

**firebase**

Como faço no firebase?

Answer (score 0):

Qual erro está apresentando? pelo menos nesse select o "or" estava junto do campo quarto.

```
select * from aparmanto where andar< 22 or quarto=>2;
```

poste a estrutura de criação da tabela também.

Comment: Este é um no sql, preciso no firebase.